# Transfer learning for DQN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning

I research how to use transfer learning in deep reinforcement learning.

I want to use the pre-trained model (h5f. file) in my project by transfer learning. I have image input and scalar inputs. The image is the input of a convolutional neural network (CNN).

I have also tried to load the weights from the pre-trained model and I have tried to decide which layers can be trainable.

```
dqn.load_weights('checkpoint_reward_176.h5f')

for i in range(4):
    model.layers[1].trainable = False

for i in range(4,8):
    model.layers[i].trainable = True
```

To sum up, How can I transfer the layers to the layers which are not trained. Is it possible to use transfer learning in this case?

I appreciate all answers, Thank you very much.

Here is the DQN code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session   
env = gym.make(args.env_name)
np.random.seed(123)
env.seed(123)
nb_actions = env.action_space.n

img_shape = env.simage.shape
vel_shape = env.svelocity.shape
dst_shape = env.sdistance.shape
geo_shape = env.sgeofence.shape


AE_shape = env.sAE.shape

img_kshape = (1,) + img_shape

#Sequential model for convolutional layers applied to image
image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4) ,activation='relu', input_shape=img_kshape, data_format = "channels_first"))
image_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),  activation='relu'))
image_model.add(Flatten())
print(image_model.summary())

#Input and output of the Sequential model
image_input = Input(img_kshape)
encoded_image = image_model(image_input)

#Inputs and reshaped tensors for concatenate after with the image
velocity_input = Input((1,) + vel_shape)
distance_input = Input((1,) + dst_shape)
geofence_input = Input((1,) + geo_shape)
vel = Reshape(vel_shape)(velocity_input)
dst = Reshape(dst_shape)(distance_input)
geo = Reshape(geo_shape)(geofence_input)


AE_input  = Input((1,) + AE_shape)
ae=Reshape(AE_shape)(AE_input)#Concatenation of image, position, distance and geofence values.
#3 dense layers of 256 units
denses = concatenate([encoded_image, vel, dst, geo, ae])
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)

#Last dense layer with nb_actions for the output
predictions = Dense(nb_actions, kernel_initializer='zeros', activation='linear')(denses)

model = Model(
        inputs=[image_input, velocity_input, distance_input, geofence_input, AE_input],
        outputs=predictions
        )
print(model.summary())


train = True

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=100000, window_length=1)                        

processor = MultiInputProcessor(nb_inputs=5)

policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=1., value_min=.1, value_test=0.0,
                              nb_steps=50000)

dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, processor=processor, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=50, 
               enable_double_dqn=True, 
               enable_dueling_network=False, dueling_type='avg', 
               target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy, gamma=.99)

dqn.compile(Adam(lr=0.00025), metrics=['mae'])'
```

Updates in DQN code:

```
# Obtaining shapes from Gym environment
img_shape = env.simage.shape
vel_shape = env.svelocity.shape
dst_shape = env.sdistance.shape
geo_shape = env.sgeofence.shape

AE_shape = env.sAE.shape

# Keras-rl interprets an extra dimension at axis=0
# added on to our observations, so we need to take it into account
img_kshape = (1,) + img_shape

input_layer = Input(shape=img_kshape)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=img_kshape, name='conv1',
               data_format="channels_first")(input_layer)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', name='conv2')(conv1)
flat1 = Flatten(name='flat1')(conv2)

auxiliary_input1 = Input(vel_shape, name='vel')
auxiliary_input2 = Input(dst_shape, name='dst')
auxiliary_input3 = Input(geo_shape, name='geo')
auxiliary_input4 = Input(AE_shape, name='ae')

denses = concatenate([flat1, auxiliary_input1, auxiliary_input2, auxiliary_input3, auxiliary_input4])
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)
denses = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses)

predictions = Dense(nb_actions, kernel_initializer='zeros', activation='linear')(denses)

model = Model(inputs=[input_layer, auxiliary_input1, auxiliary_input2, auxiliary_input3, auxiliary_input4],
              outputs=predictions)

print(model.summary())
```

[Model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNKOU.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this,  "To sum up, How can I transfer the layers to the layers which are not trained."?

Comment: First of all, Thank you for the comment. For example, I want to use the image input layer which is  input of an CNN from the pre-trained model.

Comment: So is it like, you want to import the weights of a different (same shaped) pre-trained CNN model to your non-trainable layers? The shapes of your trainable layers are different from those of the pre-trained CNN model?

Comment: Yes something like that. The shapes and other all parameters are the same. I just try to use the weights from the pre-trained model for some layers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use keras functional API to build the neural networks and concatenate the two parts. So instead of the following part in your code,

```
#Sequential model for convolutional layers applied to image
image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4) ,activation='relu', input_shape=img_kshape, data_format = "channels_first"))
image_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),  activation='relu'))
image_model.add(Flatten())
```

Use the following snippet which uses keras functional API.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=img_kshape)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4) ,activation='relu', input_shape=img_kshape, name='conv1', data_format = "channels_first")(input_layer)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),  activation='relu', name='conv2')(conv1)
flat1 = Flatten(name='flat1')(conv2)
```

Then you could define an auxiliary input layer to input all those `vel`, `dst`, `geo` tensors (use appropriate shape-I have given 5 for convenience). Finally, concatenate the layers and build the model (so use the following snippet instead of your '#3 dense layers of 256 units' snippet).

```
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
denses1 = concatenate([flat1, auxiliary_input])
denses2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses1)
denses3 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses2)
denses4 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(denses3)

model = Model(inputs=[input_layer,auxiliary_input], outputs=denses4)
```

`print (model.summary())` would yield,

```
__________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 96, 96)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 32, 24, 24)   544         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)                  (None, 15, 11, 64)   13888       conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flat1 (Flatten)                 (None, 10560)        0           conv2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux_input (InputLayer)          (None, 5)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 10565)        0           flat1[0][0]                      
                                                                 aux_input[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          2704896     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          65792       dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          65792       dense_2[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,850,912
Trainable params: 2,850,912
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Once trained, you could now freeze some layers as you have done in the original post and import the layers to the non-trainable layers as follows.

```
conv1_weights = model.get_layer('conv1').get_weights()
```

If conv1 is non-trainable, then assign the loaded weights as follows.

```
conv1.set_weights(conv1_weights)
```

I've approached your problem without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), therefore let me know of any errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail answer. I will try it and I will share the results soon.

Comment: I have changed the code as you did, and I got the similar model summary. 

I have a shaping error related with the dqn.fit. 
I will share the details.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the model summary.

The error after starting the training appears in dqn.fit:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected vel to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected vel to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

This error is happening in dqn.fit.

Before, I was reshaping the inputs, now I removed the reshape by your suggestion to create the new model. I think this can be caused by the environment since I receive the states from the gym environment

Comment: Can you output the correct `vel`,`dst`,`geo`,`AE` from your environment so that you can get rid of those `Reshape` layers. Post the full code I'll have a look when I find time.

Comment: Allright, I will check it, and I will post the codes soon.

Comment: I have uploaded the files in Github  [link] (https://github.com/Endthere)

Comment: I think the error is caused by the Input layer shape in keras. It is not caused by the gym environment. There is a reference to this issue in github [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12058)